# Alert when Parse Query doesn't return results

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

basically I am running a tinder like app, which gives you a new person everytime you are swiping.

At some point my Query doesn't give back anymore users, since all are already rejected or accepted. Any ideas how to set an alert, when my Query doesn't return users anymore?

```
       query?.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: ignoredUsers)
    // Immer nur ein Resultat pro Zeit.
    query?.limit = 1

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            //Alert raushauen für einen Error:
            let userMessage = error!.localizedDescription
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            myAlert.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return


            // Muss nicht mehr auf PFObject gecastet werden (von AnyObject?)


        } else if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {




                displayedUserId = object.objectId!

                // Name, Alter und Hashtags müssen gedownloaded werden.
                // first_name sollte es ja immer geben.
                var profilText = object["first_name"] as! String
                self.ContainerVC.nameAgeLabel.text = profilText

                if let geburtstag = object["birthday"] as? String {

                    profilText += ", " + geburtstag
                self.ContainerVC.nameAgeLabel.text = profilText


                }


                if let hashtags = object["hashtags"] as? String {

                    self.ContainerVC.hashtagTextField.text = hashtags

                }



                let imageFile = object["firstImage"] as! PFFile
                // Image muss ja erstmal gedownloaded werden.
                imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error != nil {
                        let userMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
                        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        return

                    } else {
                        if let data = imageData {

                            self.ContainerVC.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: data)
                            self.ContainerVC.miniImage.image = UIImage(data: data)

                        }

                    }

                }

            }



        }


    })


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may work.

```
...} else if let objects = objects {

            if objects.length() == 0 {
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "No Users", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
                myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {

            for object in objects {




                displayedUserId = object.objectId!

                // Name, Alter und Hashtags müssen gedownloaded werden.
                // first_name sollte es ja immer geben.
                var profilText = object["first_name"] as! String
                self.ContainerVC.nameAgeLabel.text = profilText

                if let geburtstag = object["birthday"] as? String {

                    profilText += ", " + geburtstag
                self.ContainerVC.nameAgeLabel.text = profilText


                }


                if let hashtags = object["hashtags"] as? String {

                    self.ContainerVC.hashtagTextField.text = hashtags

                }



                let imageFile = object["firstImage"] as! PFFile
                // Image muss ja erstmal gedownloaded werden.
                imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error != nil {
                        let userMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
                        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        return

                    } else {
                        if let data = imageData {

                            self.ContainerVC.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: data)
                            self.ContainerVC.miniImage.image = UIImage(data: data)

                        }

                    }

                }

            }
           }
        }
```

Just a disclaimer... your approach on querying one user every swipe is not the most effective. You could get a collection of users and then use it as a buffer for every swipe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah it seems, as I'm new to programming I will for now care, that it actually works though :I